# Why not define functions as singleton functions?

Tags: scala, package, singleton, shapeless, function-definition

Consider definition of a [singleton function](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/95e8cbf7cc9546cc1cc066d768d7a3a9de0a6725/core/src/test/scala/shapeless/poly.scala#L32) found in shapeless repo:

```
/** Polymorphic function selecting an arbitrary element from a non-empty `Set`. */
object choose extends (Set ~> Option) {
  def apply[T](s : Set[T]) = s.headOption 
}
```

Contrast it with the traditional `def` syntax in the following example:

```
package utils

object UtilWithASingleMethod {
  def isSatisfyingSomePredicate(foo: Foo): Boolean = ???
}
```

versus

```
package utils

object isSatisfyingSomePredicate extends (Foo => Boolean) {
  def apply(foo: Foo): Boolean = ???
}
```

Note how call-site now becomes

```
isSatisfyingSomePredicate(foo)
```

instead of

```
UtilWithASingleMethod.isSatisfyingSomePredicate(foo)
```

or

```
import UtilWithASingleMethod._

isSatisfyingSomePredicate(foo)
```

Personally, `UtilWithASingleMethod` package seems forced just to be able to use familiar `def` syntax but does not add any useful information.

Besides subjective downsides such as unfamiliarity, or confusion with object+apply style used in factory pattern, are there any technical downsides with singleton function definitions?

Comment: How often do you have to write packages that contain a single method?

Comment: Perhaps have multiple standalone functions, each in its own file, separated by concern, under the same package, and then compose them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why they had to create singleton objects in the file you linked is that those were not *functions*, but *polymorphic functions*, i.e. they had an `apply[T](a: F[T]): G[T]` method that is universally quantified by a type parameter `T`. This is simply not needed for ordinary functions, all it does is adding overhead of invoking the `apply` method on a singleton object `foo` instead of invoking the method `foo` directly. It doesn't help you "avoid" the packages and imports either, because you want to have this object in some package anyway, you don't want to dump it in the default root package.

If you want to avoid the "forced" `UtilWithASingleMethod` namespace, then add the `isSatisfyingSomePredicate` directly to `util`:

```
package object util {
  def isSatisfyingSomePredicate(foo: Foo): Boolean = ???
}
```

This method becomes available as soon as you import `util._`.

Comment: I see the parameterisation point. What is the value of `utils.UtilWithASingleMethod.isSatisfyingSomePredicate` vs `util.isSatisfyingSomePredicate`? There already is a package `utils`. Why package it further?

Comment: @MarioGalic If you don't want to package it further, then add the method directly to the `util` package. Fortunately, Scala has package objects for exactly that. I mean, you can literally just write `package object util { def isSatisfyingSomePredicate(f: Foo): Boolean = ??? }`, and then importing `util._` would automatically bring `isSatisfyingSomePredicate` into scope.

Answer (score 1):

Scala 3 (Dotty) supports [toplevel definitions](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/5754) so instead of

```
package utils

object UtilWithASingleMethod {
  def isSatisfyingSomePredicate(foo: Foo): Boolean = ???
}
```

we can remove the indirection and write

```
package utils

def isSatisfyingSomePredicate(foo: Foo): Boolean = ???
```

which indeed addresses my question.